# Find the largest number and its index in the random array

Tags: loops, random

This is my current code for generating a set of 20 random numbers:

```
  int[] array_1 = new int[20];
        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < array_1.Length; i++)
        {
            array_1[i] = rand.Next(10,100);
            Console.Write("{0} ", array_1[i]);



        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int highest = 0;
int highestIndex = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < array_1.Length; i++) 
{
    if (array_1[i] > highest) 
    {
        highest = array_1[i];
        highestIndex = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wrote the same code, but I forgot to include the array index.  So I just deleted my answer and gave yours an upvote. :)

Comment: what about the smallest number?

Comment: change the > to < in the if condition